# convert KAZAM video file to a file, playable in windows media player

Tags: windows, screen-casting, linux, vlc

I have some `mp4` video files that are created by [KAZAM](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kazam/) in `Linux`. But I need to play those files on `Microsoft Windows` only by `Windows Media Player` (for example I can not install [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.en_GB.html)). Also I can not use any codec. So I think `converting` propoerties of file (for example format of files) is the only solution. But I do not know which output format is best for video file

- without losing quality
- ability of playing result in `Windows Media Player`

Also I want to know how I can convert to that format?

Note:

- I prefer to use `VLC media player` for converting video files, but `ffmpeg` is also appreciable.
- Also do you know a simple, light software for `screen casting` and recording sounds from speaker in `Linux-Ubuntu 14.04` which it's output is playable directly in `Windows Media Player`? I can replace `KAZAM` by this.

Edit:

I tested output by `WMP 12 (for windows 7)` and also [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Ubuntu) says:

```
General
Complete name                            : /path/to/file/Screencast 2016-12-17 07:19:13.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42
File size                                : 314 KiB
Duration                                 : 3s 280ms
Overall bit rate                         : 783 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-12-17 03:48:54
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-12-17 03:48:54
Writing application                      : x264

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High 4:4:4 Predictive@L3.2
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 3s 280ms
Bit rate                                 : 744 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 366 pixels
Height                                   : 768 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:4:4
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.028
Stream size                              : 298 KiB (95%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2491 24e4fed
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=1 / deblock=0:0:0 / analyse=0:0 / me=dia / subme=0 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=6 / threads=4 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=cqp / mbtree=0 / qp=15 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=0
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-12-17 03:48:54
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-12-17 03:48:54

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Codec ID                                 : 6B
Duration                                 : 3s 186ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 32.0 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 12.4 KiB (4%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.99.5
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-12-17 03:48:54
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-12-17 03:48:54
```

Comment: Need to know which version of WMP. And what does [Mediainfo](http://www.mediaarea.net) say about the file? Use View-Text mode

Comment: @Mulvya I added more details in `Edit` part of question. Please see that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your KAZAM video features YUV444P pixel format which WMP may not support without extra filters. Using ffmpeg, run

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

---

You can also use ffmpeg itself to capture screen and sound on linux. Basic syntax would be

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i VIDEO -f alsa -i AUDIO -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 64k cap.mp4
```

where VIDEO is the name of the video device. See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2 for details.

AUDIO is the name of the audio device. See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#alsa

You can also use x11grab to capture from the X-Window system. See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab

Comment: :) thanks a lot for sharing the command. worked like a charm.

Comment: this saved my life today!

Comment: I left incognito mode and signed in, joined this community - just so I could upvote your answer @Gyan. Thanks for this amazing answer. God bless! :)